# Visualization of System of equations vs linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Lets consider a system of linear equation:
$2x +3y = 2$ and $x +2y =3$
The solution to this is $(-5,4)$ shown as **point of intersection** of these two line! Cool!
Now turning on to matrices making a matrix (an augmented one ) and solving give the same answer(-5,4)
the problem is here with **visualization**
I took a graph paper and draw the lines and their of point of intersection . At same time I applied linear transformation to a vector (-5,4) and transformation take it to (2,3) but these points were completely sort of **unrelated**. *The intersection point lie on the left of graph whereas the vector on the same graph plane lie on completely unrelated points!*
Maybe this is just a dumb question but i think they should be at least related a bit visually too since answers are exactly the same.